# What do you call someone with only technical knowledge of sex?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

So, I was reading a Futari Ecchi by Katsu Aki the other day and one of the characters is a female gynecologist and obstetrician, and at one point in the story after we meet her but before she has her first "experience" the narrator says that she is a ____, meaning she only has a technical knowledge of sex without any experience.

Does anyone know of what this title might be?

Edit to include all of the information from the comments:

- The term was not virgin, dilettante, sexologist, sex therapist, theoretician, unsexperinced, prude, asexual, celibate, or abstinent.
- It was an English word.
- The term was not vulgar.
- As far as I could tell, it was also more of a technical term.

Comment: @Cyberson Please help others to help you: edit the question to include **all** relevant information, including terms you don't want. *Virgin* seems most appropriate (for example). Please see our [single-word-request](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) tag info.

Comment: In the "street jargon" of erotic practices, the word "novice" applies to a person with curiosity but no experience.

Answer (score 1):

Sexless

Kyoko Omiya (大宮 杏子 Ōmiya Kyōko)
Makoto's second cousin and an obstetrician and gynecologist. At the request of Makoto's mother, she moved in next door to the Onodas to encourage them to reproduce. A very dominant personality, she was still a virgin at age thirty, but she finally does get settled down with Koichiro Matsuzaki.

39. Sexless For How Long?
40. Introducing Gynecologist Kyouko

Upd from comments: Ok, let it be *unsexperienced* :)

Answer (score 1):

Virgin.

She's a gynecologist, so she has book knowledge.

She's a virgin, so no actual experience.

Comment: As I stated earlier in one of the comments, the term was not virgin. Yes, she is a virgin, but that's not the term that was used.

Answer (score 0):

A person who has no sexual feelings or desires is ***asexual***.

Comment: She has sexual feelings, just no experience.

Answer (score 0):

***celibate*** or ***abstinent*** are two possibilities, although abstinent does not necessarily mean never having had sex, but rather is currently not active.

Comment: It's not that she was withholding herself either, she just hadn't had the chance yet.